# Данные из Википедии

Tags: xml, парсер, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Есть ли готовое решение для того, чтобы парсить данные с определенных страниц из Википедии? К примеру дату рождения и фото?
 
Или только через API? Только как?

Могу только так:

```
https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Пушкин&rvprop=content&redirects=true&format=xml
```

Но выдает всю страницу.

Answer (score 1):

У Википедии есть свой API: 
https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page/ru
Но, как вы уже заметили, там вся страница целиком. 
Для более конкретизировано результата можно использовать "wiki query language". 
http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.